# Checking current browser url with python

Tags: python, selenium, url, web, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an app that blocks some acces to certain websites, now i'm stuck thinking how to check the current url. I've tried selenium, but that doesn't work when you change tabs, so i had to try something else. I've been thinking about a chrome addon that checks current url and sends it to my python code, but i don't know how to do it without making any additional server. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Selenium has an ability to switch into a newly opened tab/window. After switching, you can get the url, have you tried that?

Comment: I didn't, but the problem is that i can't use selenium on my own browser, not the one that selenium opens

Comment: Is there a way to use selenium on your own browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium and web drive manager for this

Install webdrive manager first using

```
pip install webdrive-manager
```

Then input the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
print (driver.current_url)
```

Comment: Nah, i've tried it already and it works on only one default chrome tab